# MacOs: How to change the C++ compiler and stdlib

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, cmake, clang

I have a C++ project with CMake (and conan) and I want to switch the compiler to GCC-10, and its corresponding stdlibc++. How do I do this on MacOS (Big Sur).

Specifying -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=`which g++-10` in the cmake configure command successfully makes the switch to the g++ 10 compiler that I have on my system (installed with brew). However, I do not see any indicator that the includes and the stdlib are changed.

My buidld command looks like:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++-10 -DCONCORE_USE_GLM=1 -DCONCORE_USE_OPENMP=1 -DCONCORE_USE_TBB=1 -DRC_USE_RTTI -I../test/. -I../test/../include -I../include -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2020_U3/include -isystem /Users/lucteo/.conan/data/Catch2/2.11.0/catchorg/stable/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9/include -isystem /Users/lucteo/.conan/data/rapidcheck/20200131/_/_/package/d2dbafdccc1ddd834eb76a31bdfdc6cc51e23ec1/include -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined  -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 -O3 -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -Wall -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT test/CMakeFiles/test.concore.dir/func/test_serializers.cpp.o -MF test/CMakeFiles/test.concore.dir/func/test_serializers.cpp.o.d -o test/CMakeFiles/test.concore.dir/func/test_serializers.cpp.o -c ../test/func/test_serializers.cpp
```

What is the best way to switch the compiler and stdlib?

Comment: Did you try common export CXXFLAGS="..." and export CXX="..." before the cmake run?

Comment: Adding `export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-10 CXXFLAGS="-isystem /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/" ; cmake ...` produces the same result

Comment: You should take care when using a std lib that is not the default of the system in case you consider to link to other libraries that have an API through which you pass types of the std lib. libstdc++ and libc++ are not binary compatible.

Answer (score 0):

To change stdlib you need to provide the `-stdlib=stdlibc++` flag to the compiler in order to  activate stdlibc++. This can be done through ccmake (turn on advanced mode (with t), and set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to `-stdlib=stdlibc++`), or through an equivalent directive in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=stdlibc++")
```

You also may need `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-stdlib=stdlibc++")`:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=stdlibc++")
```

To update your conan profile (say `default`) use the command as follows:

```
conan profile update settings.compiler.libcxx=stdlibc++ default
```

**Note:** `-stdlib` is a Clang flag and will not work with any version of GCC ever released. GCC always uses `libstdc++` unless you tell it to use no standard library at all with the `-nostdlib` option (in which case you either need to avoid using any standard library features, or use `-I` and `-L` and `-l` flags to point it to an alternative set of header and library files).

Comment: I get compilation errors soon after adding those flags: `g++-10: error: unrecognized command-line option '-stdlib=stdlibc++'`

Comment: @LucianRaduTeodorescu `-stdlib` is a clang's flag not gcc. I updated the answer